# Add swipe right to delete ListView item

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I have a ListView that uses a custom adaper (that extends BaseAdapter). How do I add the swipe to delete gesture?

I want use the same functionality the gmail application uses.

Comment: You can use a library like https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView or https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout or https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: Problem is that for implements this library i must rewrite all.....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to move your `ListView` over to a `RecyclerView` and use a `GridLayoutManager` with a single column.  It will look the same, but allows you to swipe to dismiss using the `ItemTouchHelper`.

```
     recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1));

     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            // Remove item from backing list here
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: Yes, you will have to change the ListView to a RecyclerView, change the adapter base class type and then create one or more Handlers for the data.

Comment: I have do it, but now i have scroll in recycleview, i don't want scroll i have already  scrollview is possible remove scroll?

Comment: I have solved problem of scroll, my Adapter is RecyclerView.Adapter, if i want method that return item from position How i do?

Comment: i want to create my custom method delete in RecyclerView.Adapter but i have a dubt, after i have delete item from ArrayList then i call notifyDataSetChanged() or i call notifyItemRemoved() ?

Comment: Removed is probably the better choice, then the adapter knows which positions it has to redraw.  The `notifyDataSetChanged` will force it to redraw whatever is on the screen.

Comment: Last question: If i want add listner on item how i can?

Comment: From adapter is possible call onCreate activity?

Comment: Shall also implement public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {return false;}
Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lib ::

[SwipeMenuListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView)

Comment: this repo is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

**Accepted answer translated to Kotlin:**

```
val itemTouchHelper =  ItemTouchHelper(object: ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            todoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

})
this.runOnUiThread {
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A Kotlin version using a ListAdapter**

all credit goes to this blog post:
https://theeasiestwayy.medium.com/listadapter-and-swipe-to-delete-741e32e5f824 (which as a couple of typos in it's code examples)

```kotlin
abstract class ListAdapterSwipeable <T, VH: RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
    diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>
): ListAdapter<T, VH>(diffCallback) {

    private val removedItems: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()

    fun removeItem(position: Int): T? {
        if (position >= itemCount) return null
        val item = currentList[position]
        removedItems.add(item)
        val actualList = currentList - removedItems
        if (actualList.isEmpty()) removedItems.clear()
        submit(actualList, true)
        return item
    }

    private fun submit(list: List<T>?, isLocalSubmit: Boolean) {
        if (!isLocalSubmit) removedItems.clear()
        super.submitList(list)
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun submitList(list: List<T>?) {
        submit(list, false)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class ItemSwipeHandler<T>(
    private val adapter: ListAdapterSwipeable<T, *>,
    private val onItemRemoved: ((item: T) -> Unit)? = null
) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
//        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition  DEPRECATED!!
        val position = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
        val item = adapter.removeItem(position) ?: return
        onItemRemoved?.invoke(item)
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean = false
}
```

More about it's usage see the blog article from above

Answer (score -4):

The simplest way I have found is to use a `ListView.builder` in a `StatefullWidget` and wrap the children in a `Dismissible` component:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: sampleList.length, //number of items on the list
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Dismissible(
        key: Key(sampleList[index]), //unique key string for each element (in this case each string is unique)
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          setState(() {
            sampleList.removeAt(index); //remove list element at given index and repaint
          });
        },
        child: child: Text('${sampleList[index]}'), //what to display form the list
      );
  },
);
```

you can check/copy the code bellow as a working example, and pass it as a child to a component:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DismissibleList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DismissibleListState createState() => _DismissibleListState();
}

class _DismissibleListState extends State<DismissibleList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> sampleList = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']; // the list of elements
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: sampleList.length, //number of items on the list
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(sampleList[index]), //unique key string for each element (in this case each string is unique)
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {
                  sampleList.removeAt(index); //remove list element at given index and repaint
                });
              },
              child: child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), // just to help the visual
                child: Text('${sampleList[index]}'),
              ) //what to display form the list
            );
        },
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an answer for flutter. However the question targets native android